# Install Flash player without root privileges in Iceweasel (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, adobe-flash, plugin, iceweasel

I need to install Flash player in Icewesel (Firefox), but I don't want to install it globally. I only want to use it in one of my several firefox profiles.

This is similar to installing addons as a user in Firefox (inside the user's profile only). User can install any addon he wants and other users/profile on the same machine are not affected by that addon.

I have downloaded the Flash player plugin from adobe.com and placed it in my `plugins` folder:

```
~/.mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so
```

When I restart Firefox, nothing happens (I have expected the new plugin will be found upon start and activated).

When I inspect `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default/pluginreg.dat`, I see that a new entry has been added for the flashplayer plugin, but in the section `[INVALID]`:

```
[INVALID]
~/.mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so:$
1411257137000:$
```

I am sure this plugin version is compatible with my browser, because I was able to instal it on my test machine (using the standard installation method)

**How can I install Flash player locally (in one user's profile only) without root privileges?**

I am using Iceweasel (Firefox) 31.2.0 on Debian Wheezy (64-bit)

Comment: 32 or 64 bit linux? and for libflashplayer? what does `ldd libflashplayer.so` tell you? does the same library work systemwide?

Comment: @Fabian - it's 64-bit. And `ldd libflashplayer.so` tells me: not a dynamic executable

Comment: Well, then I suppose your libflashplayer.so is broken. Try redownloading it making sure its the 64 bit version. For understanding the issue at hand, can you run `file libflashplayer.so`?

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for where to put the plugin file in Quatnum, the correct location has now moved under browser so, supposing you have installed your personal copy of firefox in /home/yourname/firefox the plugin file needs to be put in the directory /home/yourname/firefox/browser/plugins/
The directory will not be there if no other plugins have been installed so create it and copy the libflashplayer.so there